# javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException

Tags: jdbc, jdo, datanucleus

Please follow My requirement flow as below.

I have to connect **2 databases** in same application.

**First database :**

```
PersistenceManagerFactory persistenceManagerf1= JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory (props1);
PersistenceManager persistenceManager1 = persistenceManagerf.getPersistenceManager ();
Query dbConnectionInfoQuery1 = persistenceManager.newQuery (Constants.QUERY_TYPE, dbInfoQuery);
List<Object[]> result = (List) dbConnectionInfoQuery.execute();
persistenceManager1.close();
persistenceManagerf1.close();
```

**Second database :**

```
PersistenceManagerFactory persistenceManagerf2= JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory (props2);
PersistenceManager persistenceManager2 = persistenceManagerf.getPersistenceManager ();
Query dbConnectionInfoQuery = persistenceManager.newQuery (Constants.QUERY_TYPE, dbInfoQuery);
List<Object[]> result = (List) dbConnectionInfoQuery.execute();
persistenceManager2.close();
persistenceManagerf2.close();
```

**Issues :**

i got 3 exceptions while running aplication ,First  connected 1st database then  closed all connections of PersistenceManager and PersistenceManagerFactory.

After that again connected to second database with different configuration and when reach the **PersistenceManagerFactory persistenceManagerf2= JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory (props2);** statement i got the exceptions like :

1. javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: A property named javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass must be specified, or a jar file with a META-INF/services/javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory entry must be in the classpath, or a property named javax.jdo.option.PersistenceUnitName must be specified.
2. NestedThrowables:javax.jdo.JDOUserException: You have either specified for this PMF to use a "persistence-unit" of "org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory@5292600e" (yet this doesnt exist!) or you called JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory with "org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory@5292600e" as the name of a properties file (and this doesnt exist in the CLASSPATH).
3. NestedThrowables:org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: No "persistence.xml" file was found in the CLASSPATH. These files should be found under the META-INF/ directory in the root of a CLASSPATH entry/jar.

   **Input :**

   **First DB url :** jdbc:com.nuodb://192.168.X.XX/SecurityDB?schema=BOSUITEDBINFO

   ```
       Map props = new HashMap ();
       props.put ("datanucleus.ConnectionDriverName", "com.nuodb.jdbc.Driver");
       props.put ("datanucleus.ConnectionURL", jdbc:com.nuodb://192.168.X.XX/SecurityDB?schema=BOSUITEDBINFO);
       props.put ("datanucleus.ConnectionUserName",    "dba");
       props.put ("datanucleus.ConnectionPassword", "dba");
       props.put ("datanucleus.autoCreateSchema",false);
       props.put ("datanucleus.autoCreateTables",false);
       props.put ("datanucleus.autoCreateColumns", false);
       props.put ("datanucleus.connectionPool.maxPoolSize", 5);
       props.put ("datanucleus.connectionPool.minPoolSize", 3);
       props.put ("datanucleus.connectionPool.maxStatements",0);
       props.put ("datanucleus.query.jdoql.allowAll", true);
       props.put ("datanucleus.query.sql.allowAll",true);
       props.put ("datanucleus.primaryClassLoader", org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory@5292600e);
       props.put ("datanucleus.rdbms.stringDefaultLength", 24000);
   ```

   **Second DB url:** jdbc:com.nuodb://192.168.X.XX/BSuiteDB?schema=BSuiteInfo

Thanks.

Comment: yet you don't mention what is the input to the PMF, so how can anyone comment, other than point out the advice in the exceptions? All exceptions have stack traces

Comment: No idea what _"datanucleus.primaryClassLoader", org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory@5292600e_ is trying to achieve. A PMF is not a ClassLoader! Don't see "props2" there. Look at the log. Also you quote 3 exceptions BUT don't state what you got and with what input.